# ReadFile std::unique_ptr vs. std::vector vs. std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Which one of the following would be the most efficient and why? I'm leaning towards the `unique_ptr` because I think that there is no copy being done when returning the data read. It's just a transfer of ownership of a pointer.

For example, I think that the string version would create a temporary string, read data into that, and upon returning, it'd copy its data into the assigned result?

However, I'm not sure that I'm right. Any ideas what I mean and which is the best?

**UniquePtr:**

```
std::unique_ptr<const char[]> ReadFile(const char* FileName)
{
    std::fstream file(FileName, std::ios::in);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::size_t size = file.tellg();
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> result(new char[size]);
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(result.get(), size);
        file.close();
        return std::move(result);
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

**Vector:**

```
std::string ReadFile(const char* FileName)
{
    std::fstream file(FileName, std::ios::in);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::vector<std::int8_t> buffer(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(result.data(), result.size());
        file.close();
        return std::string(result.data());
    }
    return std::string();
}
```

**String:**

```
std::string ReadFile(const char* FileName)
{
    std::fstream file(FileName, std::ios::in);

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::string result = std::string();
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        result.resize(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(&result[0], result.size());
        file.close();
        return result;
    }
    return std::string();
}
```

Comment: Your `unique_ptr<char>` should be a `unique_ptr<char[]>`! Anyway, returning by value moves if NRVO doesn't happen. Copying is a last resort.

Comment: Ok thank you for that. Changed. Oh and is the `std::unique_ptr` the only one guaranteed to be moved?

Comment: More than likely, you won't see much (if any) performance difference in these blocks of code.  Copy elision in the `std::string` version will get effectively behave in a similar fashion to the pointer.  The `std::vector` version might have a couple milliseconds of copying the vector into the string, but for most data sizes, that will hardly be noticeable.  The main issue will be if that file is large, as all of these containers require contiguous memory blocks.  If you are really trying to squeeze out performance, profile each of them on the system you are compiling it on.

Comment: `std::string result = std::string();` should be just `std::string result;` -- the compiler might elide the copy, but why hope when you can require.

Comment: One possible drawback to returning `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` is you won't know how much data was read. Both `std::string` and `std::vector` have a `size()` member function.

Comment: `std::string(result.data())` only compiles if `char` happens to be signed in your compiler environment, then doesn't handle embedded NULs, and can try to read past the end of result's data.  You should explicitly case to `const char*` and pass `.size()` as a second parameter to `std::string::string(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string ReadFile(const char* FileName)
{
    std::fstream file(FileName, std::ios::in);
    std::string result = std::string();

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        result.resize(file.tellg());
        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(&result[0], result.size());
        file.close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have no proof , but if function has only one return , copy elision might be  implemented  by compiler ,  if there are 2 returns inside function , 
copy elision might not work as expected ~~~

Comment: Note that with the filesystem library of C++17 you can use `std::filesystem::file_size()` to get a file's length. For GNU CC you need to link against the library explicitly with `-lstdc++fs` and to tell the compiler you're using C++17 with `-std=c++17` or `-std=gnu++17` if you want the GNU extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
 return std::string(result.data());
```

will only work if the data is null-terminated.

Apart from that complication it needlessly copies from a vector to a string.

The `std::string` code is most natural for reading text (text mode open of file).

You won't see much of a performance difference since the file i/o dwarfs the rest, but anyway with C++03 you will most likely get Return Value Optimization (depends on compiler), and with C++11 you will get move optimization of the result if you just use `std::move`.

Comment: I'm not so sure about all this seeking action on text mode streams. I believe that it's at least a bit fishy. I leave it to others to check though.